# Why can't I install libzmq in order to have ratchet working ? (Websocket)

Tags: macos, websocket, ratchet

Not sure if I'm posting on the correct Stack Exchange forum. Please redirect me to the proper one if needed.

When setting up Ratchet, I need to install ZeroMQ and I am stuck at the libzmq installation:

I have followed the instructions https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/INSTALL
I'm on mac os X 10.9

when doing the following command:

> ./autogen.sh

here is what I get:

> autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
>
> autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
>
> autoreconf: running: aclocal -I config --force -I config
>
> main::scan_file() called too early to check prototype at /opt/lo/bin/aclocal line 617.
>
> autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
>
> autoreconf: configure.ac: subdirectory
>
> foreign/openpgm/build-staging/openpgm/pgm/ not present
>
> autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
>
> autoreconf: running: /opt/lo/bin/autoconf --include=config --force
> configure.ac:57: error:
> possibly undefined macro: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL If this token and
> others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow. See the Autoconf
> documentation.
>
> configure.ac:58: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
>
> configure:5242: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DISABLE_STATIC
>
> configure:5246: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_ENABLE_STATIC
>
> autoreconf: /opt/lo/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
>
> autogen.sh: error: autoreconf exited with status 0

And I can't have it working.

Please help

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me when installing a different package. The fix was to install `libtool` with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libtool
```

then run:

```
$ ./auto_gen.sh
```

then you can proceed as normal:

```
$ ./configure && make
$ sudo make install
```